# Can't propose question on area51 site in definition phase?

Tags: support, area-51, example-questions, definition-phase

I am able to enter my question in the edit box, but the 'Post' button does nothing. I don't see anything about this in the FAQ.

Comment: Do you have javascript enabled?

Comment: Javascript is enabled. For better or worse, It's pretty hard to use the web these days unless it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your question too long or too short?  I've had this happen where I click Submit a couple times with no apparent result before I notice a message about a problem with my question.

Comment: It claims I have 49 characters left. I believe the lower limit is 15 - based on a message I've seen when first entering text. I suppose what I'm wondering is 'is this a bug?' or 'is this obscure or non-existent documentation?', and if it's the latter, where do I find the answer?

Comment: It's a bug - I remember now, when this happened to me I shortened my question and it let me submit.

Comment: Ah! I suppose I need to determine be trial and error how short is short enough...

Comment: My Bad. (Although I'm willing to share the blame if anyone else is willing to accept it.) I did not have 49 characters left, I had -49 characters left. I'm afraid I have spent so many years trying to make user-friendly interfaces, that I'd forgotten what a geek-intuitive interface looked like, and did not read the '-' as a minus sign. Simply preventing further entry when the limit was reached, as I've seen on dozens of other sites, would have been unambiguously obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how the area51 site proposals work internally, so this is going to be just speculation, but it could always be a browser-side issue. Could you try testing a question post using a different web browser?

EDIT: Just making sure; is javascript enabled?

Comment: Nope. Worth a try, but no joy.